# How can I retreive value from firebase and add value into it and update to firebase in android studio JAVA

Tags: java, android, firebase

Im newbie in android studio, trying to implement a system with Rewards point function.
In my signup, when user successfully registered an account, it automatically will have 1000 points.

[the cloud database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYEBu.png)

Then, in my reward fragment. I got 1 Button which is called addButton and another 1 is textView with the name currentPoint,

[my reward fragment interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orklH.png)

Then, this is my code which i only read it out and trying to add.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reward, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    user = currentUser.getDisplayName();
    loadUser();
    return view;
}
private void loadUser(){

    DocumentReference docRef = mFirestore.collection("UserInfo").document(currentUser.getUid());
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            mCurrentPoint.setText(document.get("points").toString());
        }
    });
}
```

The final outcome that i want is, to have the digit from firebase, and add 200 in while update to firebase. Please help me.

Comment: Please post what error you get ?

Comment: Sorry, the error has been fixed 1 min ago by adding some declaration// The code above is the latest 1.

Comment: See if my answer helps you or no

Comment: What have you tried in code for the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something to add points in previous amount.

```
Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_points);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
            DocumentReference docRef = mFirestore.collection("UserInfo").document(currentUser.getUid());
            docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    int freePoints = -200;
                    Double points = Double.parseDouble(document.get("points").toString());
                    Map<String,Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
                    updates.put("points", points + freePoints);
                    docRef.update(updates).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Points successfully updated!");
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
         } 
});
```